# How to retrieve the duid used in the dhcpv6 client

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6

I m using odhcp6c as DHCPv6 client

I want to know the DUID used by the my interface in the DHCPv6. How to retrieve the DUID?

Answer (score 0):

Use `wireshark` to sniff the network traffic and get the packet used during the **dhcp** handshake, then look for the DUID in the packet.